# Implement a method with abort ability

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

How can I implement a method with abort ability?

Imagine I have a grid, when data loads the grid starts calculating the totals and show them on another grid beneath itself. I want to start calculating totals right after loading data.

I tried using threads but a problem rose up:
When I click on Load button two rapid times, for the first time the thread starts working and the second time I get an error saying the thread is busy.

I need to implement some method that can be aborted and started again.

Comment: Can you post some code? Don't try to abort, instead you can implement co-operative cancellation.

Comment: As others have suggested, you can use tasks and cooperative cancellation. Here is a very good introduction on the topic: ["Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx). Specifically, you may be interested in "Canceling a Task" section of ["Parallel Tasks"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I would indeed use threads. Depending on your .NET framework you can start by setting up an `IProgress` object which can be used to provides UI updates from a background thread-pool thread. So firstly you could create

```
IProgress<object> progressIndicator =
    new Progress<object>(ReportProgress);
```

where `ReportProgress` is some method

```
public void ReportProgress(object o) { /* Update UI components here on the Main UI thread */ }
```

Now, to start the work and provide cancellation support, you can do some thing like

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        // Do your work here and provide cancellation support.
        for (int i = 0; i < someMaxValue; ++i)
        {
            // Update the UI if required.
            progressIndicator.ReportProgress(someObject);

            // No check for you cancellation condition...
            if (source != null && someCancelCondition)
                source.Cancel(); // This will throw a CancellationException().
        }
    }, token, 
       TaskCreationOptions.None, 
       TaskScheduler.Default)
           .ContinueWith(ant => 
           {
                // Here you must handle you exceptions and trap your cancellation. 
           });
```

For more information see [J. Albahari's Threading tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

When load is clicked, create a [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) and store it. Pass in its `CancellationToken` to your worker thread, and check it regularly in your calculations so you can abort in a timely manner.

When Load is clicked again, you can abort the current thread by calling `Cancel()` on your TokenSource.

Comment: +1 for pointing in right direction, but it is no longer called `Abort` it is co-operative cancellation